# Can I send balances to Segwit address from non-segwit address?

Tags: sendtoaddress, segregated-witness

I have some balance on my first exchange. It use 1~ address.

I'm trying to withdraw this balance to my Bitcoin Core's 3~ address.(Which is Segwit address, right? I made this by addwitnessaddress command)

Does this situation accepted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to withdraw this balance to my Bitcoin Core's 3~ address. (Which is Segwit address, right? I made this by addwitnessaddress command)

Kind of. Addresses which start with 3 are known as Pay-to-Script-Hash addresses (P2SH). Because you used the `addwitnessaddress` command, your one will be a segwit P2SH yes. But not all addresses which start with 3 are for segwit, they are commonly multisig addresses or could be many other things.

> Does this situation accepted?

Yes, there should be no difference to your exchange between sending to an address starting with a 3 and an address starting with a 1.